# How to give a text file as an input to speech synthesis Speak method

Tags: c#, speech-synthesis

I am developing an application in C# where I would like to read from a simple text file. So how to give input(the file) to speak synthesis Engine.Speak() method.

Comment: Have you got any idea yet? or maybe some code to show us how far is your progress. We really want you to **Learn** instead of just copy and paste. Also , I still don't understand your need , do you want how to get input from file into program , or you already have input into your program but you want to speak it out.

Comment: As of now, I am only giving the Speak() method some predefined strings. I just want to know how to do it for a file instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your comment and [this guide](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezwyzy7b.aspx)

I'll give you example how to get a text file's content into your program.

Example 1: Read all text and save into string.

```
 string alltext= System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"read.txt");
 Engine.Speak(alltext); //put the string into your command
```

Example 2: Read each line of file and save into string array.

```
 string[] eachlinetext = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\Users\Public\TestFolder\WriteLines2.txt");
 Engine.Speak(eachlinetext[0]); // speak the first line of the file
```

Hope it helps you. Also , Happy Programming!!

Comment: This is exactly what I want. Secondly, how to do reverse of that as in how to give the recognizer an audio file as input.

Comment: do you have an engine to assign the regcognized text into  string?

Comment: I hope it could be done using Speech Recognition Engine provided in System.Speech.Recognition.

Comment: I think it could be done using Speech Recognition Engine in System.Speech

Comment: @user3755903 see this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.setinputtoaudiostream.aspx . WARNING:You may be dissappointed by speech regcognition engine. So be patient doing things with this stuff.